# Mapping in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Good morning, In my code I can't search data which contain separate words. If I search on one word all good. I think problem in mapping. I use postman. When I put in URL `http://192.168.1.153:9200/sport_scouts/video/_mapping` and use method GET I get:

```
{
  "sport_scouts": {
    "mappings": {
      "video": {
        "properties": {
          "hashtag": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "sharing_link": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "user_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "video_preview": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All good title have type string but if I search on two or more words I get empty massive. My code in Trait:

```
public function search($data) {

        $this->client();

        $params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['or'][]['term']['title'] = $data;
        $search = $this->client->search($params)['hits']['hits'];
        dump($search);
    }
```

Then I call it in my Controller. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: What's the problem you are having?

Comment: The elastic doesn't search on two or more words, it return empty massive, elastic search only on one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your indexed data can't be found is caused by a mismatch of the analyzing during indexing and a strict term filter when querying the data.

With your mapping configuration, you are using the default analyzing which (besides many other operations) does a tokenizing. So every multi-word data you insert is split at punctuation or whitespaces. If you insert for example "some great sentence", elasticsearch maps the following terms to your document: "some", "great", "sentence", but not the term "great sentence". So if you do a term filter on "great sentence" or any other part of the original value containing a whitespace, you will not get any results.

Please see the elasticsearch docs on how to configure your mapping for indexing without analyzing (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2) or consider doing a `match query` instead of a `term filter` on the existing mapping (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

Please be aware that if you switch to `not_analyzed` you will be disabling many of the great fuzzy fulltext query functionality. Of course you can set up a mapping that does both, analyzed and not_analyzed in different fields. Then it's up on you to decide on which field you want to query on.